# How to increase an array's length

Tags: java, arrays

I have a quick question. I have an integer array in java that needs its length to vary throughout the class. Specifically, I need it to increase by one in certain situations. I tried  it like this.

```
        sbgHeadX = new int[ numberOfSBG ];
```

I would increase the integer variable numberOfSBG when I needed to, but I don't think this works. Is there any other way?

Comment: Can you provide a reasonable maximum.  Obviously your array can never be larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE , but if you know that your array can also never be larger than 300 you could just set its length to 300.

Comment: @emory - personally, I would consider doing so to be a strong code smell: the result is an array, some of whose elements are "not supposed to be used". That's an error-prone and clumsy coding style, requiring passing around a separate variable with the number of valid elements. Also breaks the assumption that `.size()` yields the number of elements to work with.

Comment: If you're not going to use an ArrayList, you will have to recreate it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would suggest you use an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) as you won't have to worry about the length anymore. Once created, you can't modify an array size:

> An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of a single type. The length of an array is established when the array is created. After creation, its length is fixed.

([Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html))

Comment: how would I access a specific index of the arraylist?

Comment: @user1276078 `yourArraylist.get(2)` is the equivalent of `yourClassicArray[2]`

Comment: While this works, this may cause unnecessary autoboxing, as the OP indicated it was a primitive int.  Java collections require Objects as their value, so the JVM will convert all values to Integer every time the collections method are called.  This could add up to being costly over time.  Obviously, the programmer needs to decide if it's worth the 'overhead' of doing something like Hunter McMillen suggests below, but his answer is, IMHO, a more accurate answer to the question.

Comment: OP asked how to change an array's size, he didn't ask for an alternative to an array. -1

Answer (score 36):

If you don't want or cannot use ArrayList, then there is a utility method:

```
Arrays.copyOf()
```

that will allow you to specify new size, while preserving the elements.

Comment: @TheUnfunCat yep. I have deleted it. Thanks

Answer (score 25):

Arrays in Java are of fixed size that is specified when they are declared. To increase the size of the array you have to create a new array with a larger size and copy all of the old values into the new array.

ex:

```
char[] copyFrom  = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' };
char[] copyTo    = new char[7];

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(copyFrom));
System.arraycopy(copyFrom, 0, copyTo, 0, copyFrom.length);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(copyTo));
```

Alternatively you could use a dynamic data structure like a List.

Comment: IMHO, using `Arrays.copyOf()`, as in Jakub's answer, would give shorter, more readable, code.

Answer (score 3):

First things first:

- In Java, once an array is created, it's length is fixed. Arrays cannot be resized.
- You can copy the elements of an array to a new array with a different size. The easiest way to do this, is to use one of the [`Arrays.copyOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-T:A-int-) methods.
- If you need a collection of variable size, you're probably better off using an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of an array.

That being said, there might be situations where you have no other choice than to change the size of an array that is created somewhere outside of your code.<sup>1</sup> The only way to do that is to manipulate the generated bytecode of the code that creates the array.

#### Proof-of-concept

Below is a small proof-of-concept project that uses Java [instrumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) to dynamically change the size of an array<sup>2</sup>. The sample project is a maven project with the following structure:

```
.
├─ pom.xml
└─ src
   └─ main
      └─ java
         └─ com
            └─ stackoverflow
               └─ agent
                  ├─ Agent.java
                  └─ test
                     └─ Main.java
```

**`Main.java`**

This file contains the target class of which we're going to manipulate the bytecode:

```
package com.stackoverflow.agent.test;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] array = {"Zero"};

        fun(array);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }

    public static void fun(String[] array) {
        array[1] = "One";
        array[2] = "Two";
        array[3] = "Three";
        array[4] = "Four";
    }
}
```

In the `main` method, we create a `String` array of size 1. In the `fun` method, 4 additional values are assigned outside of the array's bounds. Running this code as-is will obviously result in an error.

**`Agent.java`**

This file contains the class that will perform the bytecode manipulation:

```
package com.stackoverflow.agent;

import java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer;
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;

public class Agent {
    public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation instrumentation) {
        instrumentation.addTransformer(new ClassFileTransformer() {
            public byte[] transform(ClassLoader l, String name, Class<?> c,
                    ProtectionDomain d, byte[] b) {

                if (name.equals("com/stackoverflow/agent/test/Main")) {
                    byte iconst1 = (byte) 0x04;
                    byte iconst5 = (byte) 0x08;
                    byte anewarray = (byte) 0xbd;

                    for (int i = 0; i <= b.length - 1; i++) {
                        if (b[i] == iconst1 && b[i + 1] == anewarray) {
                            b[i] = iconst5;
                        }
                    }

                    return b;
                }

                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

On the bytecode level, the creation of the `String` array in the `Main` class consists of two commands:

- [`iconst_1`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.iconst_i), which pushes an `int` constant with value 1 onto the stack (`0x04`).
- [`anewarray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.anewarray), which pops the value of the stack and creates a reference array<sup>3</sup> of the same size (`0xbd`).
  The above code looks for that combination of commands in the `Main` class, and if found, replaces the `const_1` command with a `const_5` command (`0x08`), effectively changing the dimensions of the array to 5.<sup>4</sup>

**`pom.xml`**

The maven POM file is used to build the application JAR and configure the main class and the Java agent class.<sup>5</sup>

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>agent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
              <Main-Class>com.stackoverflow.agent.test.Main</Main-Class>
              <Premain-Class>com.stackoverflow.agent.Agent</Premain-Class>
              <Agent-Class>com.stackoverflow.agent.Agent</Agent-Class>
              <Can-Retransform-Classes>true</Can-Retransform-Classes>
            </manifestEntries>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

#### Build and execute

The sample project can be built using the standard `mvn clean package` command.

Executing without referencing the agent code will yield the expected error:

```
$> java -jar target/agent.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at com.stackoverflow.agent.test.Main.fun(Main.java:15)
        at com.stackoverflow.agent.test.Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

While executing with the agent code will yield:

```
$> java -javaagent:target/agent.jar -jar target/agent.jar
[Zero, One, Two, Three, Four]
```

This demonstrates that the size of the array was successfully changed using bytecode manipulation.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Such situations came up in questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000604/java-reflection-editing-array-length) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844279/modify-array-size-passed-as-argument-to-method-in-java), the latter of which prompted me to write this answer.

<sup>2</sup> Technically, the sample project doesn't resize the array. It just creates it with a different size than the size specified in code. Actually resizing an existing array while maintaining its reference and copying its elements would be a fair bit more complicated.

<sup>3</sup> For a primitive array, the corresponding bytecode operation would be [`newarray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.newarray) (`0xbc`) instead.

<sup>4</sup> As noted, this is just a proof of concept (and a very hacky one at that). Instead of randomly replacing bytes, a more robust implementation could use a bytecode manipulation library like [ASM](https://asm.ow2.io/) to insert a [`pop`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.pop) command followed by an [`sipush`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.sipush) command before any [`newarray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.newarray) or [`anewarray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.anewarray) command. Some more hints towards that solution can be found in the comments to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12000695).

<sup>5</sup> In a real-world scenario, the agent code would obviously be in a separate project.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of ArrayList. Array has the fixed number of size.

This [Example](http://www.java2novice.com/java-interview-programs/arraylist-implementation/) here can help you. The example is pretty easy with its output.

```
Output:
2 5 1 23 14 

New length: 20 

Element at Index 5:29 

List size: 6 

Removing element at index 2: 1 

2 5 23 14 29
```

Answer (score 1):

By definition arrays are fixed size. You can use instead an Arraylist wich is that, a "dynamic size" array. Actually what happens is that the VM "adjust the size"* of the array exposed by the ArrayList.

[See also](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

*using back-copy arrays

Comment: *"Actually what happens is that the VM adjust the size of the array exposed by the arraylist."*.  Incorrect.  In fact, the code for `ArrayList` creates a new backing array and copies the contents of the existing one.  Array lengths cannot be changed ... even by the JVM.  It would be a violation of the Java Language Specification.

Comment: You are still only half right.  It is not the JVM making the adjustment.  The `ArrayList` class does it ... in ordinary Java code.  And the array is NOT exposed by the array list ... it is a private object that is HIDDEN by the array list.

Comment: And when you say "using copy-back arrays", the next question a Java newbie is going to ask is ... "What is a copy-back array".  And the answer to that is that there is no such thing.  What I think you really mean is ... well ... "the code for ArrayList creates a new backing array and copies the contents of the existing one to it".

Answer (score 1):

```
Item[] newItemList = new  Item[itemList.length+1];
    //for loop to go thorough the list one by one
    for(int i=0; i< itemList.length;i++){
        //value is stored here in the new list from the old one
        newItemList[i]=itemList[i];
    }
    //all the values of the itemLists are stored in a bigger array named newItemList
    itemList=newItemList;
```

Answer (score 1):

Example of Array length change method (with old data coping):

```
static int[] arrayLengthChange(int[] arr, int newLength) {
    int[] arrNew = new int[newLength];
    System.arraycopy(arr, 0, arrNew, 0, arr.length);
    return arrNew;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't increase the array's length if it is not declared in heap memory (see below code which first array input is asked by user and then it asks how much you want to increase array and also copy previous array elements):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int * increasesize(int * p,int * q,int x)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
         q[i]=p[i];
    }
    free(p);
    p=q;
    return p;
}
void display(int * q,int x)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        printf("%d \n",q[i]);
        
    }
}

int main()
{
    int x,i;
    printf("enter no of element to create array");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    int * p=(int *)malloc(x*sizeof(int));
    printf("\n enter number in the array\n");
    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&p[i]);
    }
    int y;
    printf("\nenter the new size to create new size of array");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    int * q=(int *)malloc(y*sizeof(int));
    display(increasesize(p,q,x),y);
    free(q);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

answering to your question without saying something in the likes of "use an ArrayList", which may not always be an option, specially when you want the best performance:

There is no native method to do that, but you can use something in the likes of this:

```
int[] newArray = new int[oldArray.length + 1];
System.arrayCopy(oldArray, 0, newArray, 0, oldArray.length);
oldArray = newArray;
```

And that's it, the last position is free to use. Note that you can change the "1" to any number that pleases you. You can also make a method out of this code, if you use it repeatedly.