# Java Reflection - Editing Array Length

Tags: java, reflection

I was wondering if it is possible to change to change the length of a class's integer array using the Java Reflection API. If so, how?

Comment: Whatever you use, it's impossible to change the length of an array.

Comment: I'm sure you know best, but perhaps if you explain more about your problem, someone may be able to find an answer for you that doesn't involve hacking into a class' internal data.

Answer (score 4):

Nope; an array is created with a fixed length.

What you *can* do is get close by modifying the value of the field with a *copy* in **larger** array (using [`Arrays.copyOf`](http://goo.gl/O3Xga)), so long as you know modifying like this won't cause any inconsistency.

```
/* desired length */
final int desired = ...;
/* the instance of the object containing the int[] field */
final Object inst = ...;
/* the handle to the int[] field */
final Field field = ...;
field.set(inst, Arrays.copyOf((int[]) field.get(inst), desired));
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to change array length even with Reflection.

This is a reference from java tutorial.

> An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of a single type. The length of an array is established when the array is created. After creation, its length is fixed.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Based on what you told me I feel like my only option is to use a bytecode manipulator such as ASM to edit the declaration of the array.

Comment: @user1606034 if you do wish to modify the array length like that, why not just recompile the source code? Pointless to do work at a lower-level than necessary.

Comment: @user1606034 if you **do** need to use bytecode for whatever reason,  [`newarray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.newarray) consumes the top word of the operand stack to determine the size. You can modify the size by merely inserting before the `newarray` a [`pop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.pop) followed by a push instructon for the desired size (e.g. [`sipush 32767`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.sipush)).

Comment: I'm reflecting a java application that I didn't write, therefore I do not have the source files.

Comment: Is it necessary to change length of you containter\, why don't you use dynamic containers from the java.lang.util such as ArrayList which is also a resizeable array internally ?

Comment: @user1606034 Just use ArrayList it will alow you to change length as many time as you want.

Comment: @AmitDeshpande he is not dealing with code that he has access to the source for.

Comment: @veer So in the instruction "sipush 32767", the length of the array will be set to 32767?

Comment: @user1606034 if you inserted that instruction (along with a preceding `pop`) directly before the `newarray`, then yes. Using ASM's tree API, you can craft this using [`new IntInsnNode(Opcodes.SIPUSH, 32767)`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/tree/IntInsnNode.html)

Comment: I wrote an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53848190/3558960) that manipulates the size of an array on the bytecode level, and references some of the comments to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

An array is a fixed length data structure, so there is no way that it's length will be modified. Nevertheless, one can create a new array with a new fixed length in such way it can accommodate new members using

> System.arrayCopy()

It is like you have an array of type T with the size of 2,

> T[] t1 = new T[2]

and it is length is fixed with 2. So it can not store any more than 2 elements. But by creating new array with a new fixed length, say 5,

> T[] t2 = new T[5]

So it can accommodate 5 elements now. Now copy the contents of the t1 to t2  using

> System.arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int
>   length)

in this case of the example,

> System.arraycopy(t1, 0, t2, 0, t1.length)

Now in the new array, you have position

> from t1.length to t2.length-1

is available for you to use.

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12000668/591495). It's much simpler to use `Arrays.copyOf` than to manually allocate a new array and call `System.arraycopy`.

Comment: Array.copyOf() internally uses System.arrayCopy() anyways. So I don't much of a simplicity, but it may be because I have been used to using System.arrayCopy(). Thanks.

Comment: There is no guarantee that `Arrays.copyOf` uses `System.arraycopy` internally, but yes in OpenJDK 7, [it does](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.copyOf%28int%5B%5D%2Cint%29). I recognized that hence I stated it's much simpler to use `copyOf` over **manually** allocating and copying using `System.arraycopy`. :p

Comment: May be you should take a look at the source of Arrays.java.

Comment: Maybe you should read my comment, considering I linked to the OpenJDK 7 code for `Arrays.java`, in particular to `copyOf(int[], int)` -- confirming that it used `System.arraycopy`. My point was that OpenJDK is not the only JDK implementation. You can't definitively state `Arrays.copyOf` uses `System.arraycopy` internally when it's not at all a guaranteed invariant. Nothing in the [API specification](http://goo.gl/O3Xga) states that it must be implemented as such. Other API implementations are free to implement it however they'd like.

Answer (score 0):

I guess java will not allow you to change array length but yes you can set value at index using reflection.

```
 import java.lang.reflect.*;

 public class array1 {
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
     try {
        Class cls = Class.forName(
          "java.lang.String");
        Object arr = Array.newInstance(cls, 10);
        Array.set(arr, 5, "this is a test");
        String s = (String)Array.get(arr, 5);
        System.out.println(s);
     }
     catch (Throwable e) {
        System.err.println(e);
     }
  }
 }
```