# Java add place to array with a limited number of places

Tags: java, arrays

I want to add place the "a" array:
My code:

```
Integer[] a = new Integer[3];
```

I want that: "Integer[] a = new Integer[3]" become to: "Integer[] a = new Integer[4]"

I tried:

```
a.length += 1;
```

and:

```
a[] = a [a.length + 1];
```

Comment: Why not use an ArrayList?

Comment: I wanted to know if that was possible

Comment: You can't https://stackoverflow.com/a/10255420/13490121

Comment: `Arrays.copy()` is your only solution. Under the hood `ArrayList<>()` does the exact same thing only you dont get to see it. Also in my opinion, if you know about the size of your data. You better go with initialisation of an `Array` or initialise `ArrayList<>(initial_size);`

Comment: OK I got it. great

Comment: If you want to "increase the size of your manually" you can actually create a new array with the size you want, and copy your array inside the new one, then you got a fresh new array with a new size. But as others already say, you can't increase the size of an array.

Comment: Yes, like @papaya said

Comment: Then I can create identical lists!

Comment: Good idea, everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the size of an array. You can, however, replace the old array with a new one of the required size to which some or all of the contents of the old array have been copied:

```
    Integer a = new Integer[3];
    a[0] =1; a[1] = 2; a[2] = 3;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)); // Prints [1,2,3]

    a = Arrays.copyOf(a, 4);
    a[3] = 4;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)); // prints [1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.copy()` is your only solution. As suggested ArrayList<>() is also a possible solution.

But under the hood `ArrayList<>()` when it reaches its size limit, this is a highly tiresome thing when handling large lists in a small heap, and will run out of memory.

Also in my opinion, if you know about the size of your data. You better go with initialisation of an `Array` or initialise `ArrayList<>(initial_size)`;